# Use of undeclared type 'XMLDocument'

Tags: xml, swift, xcode

I want to work with XML documents and found the XMLDocument class in the Foundation package which seems sufficient for my purposes. But I have some problems to use it. I have the following Swift code:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let doc = XMLDocument()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

But if I try to compile this small program then I get the error "Use of undeclared type 'XMLDocument'"

Swift 3, Xcode 8.2

Answer (score 6):

The `XMLDocument` class is only part of the macOS SDK.

Comment: Oh and is there an alternative for iOS programming?

Comment: In Foundation there is the XMLParser class but its only for parsing the documents.